# Fix the map in atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, atlas-generator

I am trying to make an atlas of a terrain that we divide in diferent plots. I would like to have in each map of the atlas each plot highlighted, but seeing allways the complete map, as you can see in this image.[image]

The problem when I generate the atlas is that it automatically moves the plots to the center of the image and I lose parts of the terrain, as in this image:

[image]

I know I can fix the scale, but I would like to fix the situation of the map for all the atlas.

Comment: You can also fix the X and Y values for the map, right below the scale. Though I do not know, whether it keeps changing when you build an atlas, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your composer window, select the map and go into **Item properties**. Make sure that the **Controlled by atlas** setting is unchecked. Then set the map extent to cover the complete map as in your first picture.

[image: atlas composer settings]

You should then be able to switch between atlas features without it changing the extent. Here is an excerpt from an example of Wisconsin State Senate Districts with the same settings:

[image: atlas output]

Comment: ThanksJoshC, but that way I have to export each image manually. In this case I have only 25, but I have another job to do with 300 plots, and I would like to generate the maps automatically with the atlas generator.

Comment: The above example was exported collectively using the atlas generator. There's no reason you have to do it one by one.

Comment: Exactly, I exported as image with the atlas control unchecked and worked. Thanks

Comment: Thank was helpful @jcarlson